# Zpanel phpmyadmin lost password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am moving my websites with cPanel management to a new VPS (more cheap and powerful) with zPanel management (the 10.1.1 version, apparently without huge security holes)

But unluckily, I lose all data that zPanel installation generated.
The lost data included phpmyadmin password and login.

Can I recover it without reinstalling zPanel? Also, if I need to reinstall, I will lose my data? Or just reinstalling zPanel over the old installation by the SSH will not affect my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!

When installed zPanel create a file named as passwords.txt.
To view the file you just need log in ssh and write:

```
vi passwords.txt
```

to exit just write:

```
 :quit
```

and press enter.